# How to change shortcut icons dynamically on home screen in Android

Tags: android, icons, homescreen

How we can change the shortcut icon of application dynamically on Homescreen. For instance, if user wants to change the shortcut icon of Browser application. Is it possible? if yes, then please give some reference. Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK here is no direct way of changing the icons of preinstalled apps **dyanmically** on the homescreen.

However, you can install [desktop-visualizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.bii.android.app.dskvzr&hl=en) to change the icons on the homescreen

Procedure

1. download the icons
2. copy/unzip to your phones sdcard
3. install Desktop Visualizer, its for free at the market.
4. long press on the homescreen and choose the widget "Desktop-Visualizer". there u can make shortcuts and choose also the size